# DJ_REST_AUTH Error : NameError: name 'dj_rest_auth' is not defined

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have installed [dj-rest-auth](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)for Token Authentication.

My urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

    
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    
    path('customer/', include('customer.urls')), #new
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')), # new
    path('customer/dj-rest-auth/', include(dj_rest_auth.urls)),
]
```

Settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'customer',
    'rest_framework.authtoken', # new
    'dj_rest_auth',
]
```

My Requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
dj-rest-auth==2.1.11
Django==3.2.7
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.12.4
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

But when I am trying to **runserver** It's giving me

> NameError: name 'dj_rest_auth' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), you should include it as a string `"dj_rest_auth.urls"` and not `dj_rest_auth.urls` from which it fails to find where `dj_rest_auth` is defined:

```
path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls'))
```

This is aligned with the usage of [django.urls.include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.include) which expects it to be the module name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really fast.